# Filtering Results across multiple columns

Tags: t-sql

I am running a query where the results look something like this:

```
          JOHN   JILL   GARY   JANE   JEFF   MICK 
RED     | NOPE |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |
ORANGE  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |
YELLOW  |  OK  |  OK  | NOPE |  OK  | NOPE |  OK  |
GREEN   |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |
BLUE    |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |
INDIGO  |  OK  | NOPE |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |
VIOLET  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  | NOPE |
```

I want to filter out the records where all columns are OK. I only want to see results where one or more of the columns contain a NOPE result.

I have tried lots of different variations where this <> to that or that = this and I give up, I need help.

Comment: Not clear on question, what you are trying to achieve? Am I missing something?

Comment: I was looking for a way to filter results so Orange, Green, Blue were omitted because all columns were OK. I only wanted to see the records where 1 or more NOPE's existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that the number of columns is constant then a where clause looking for where all are OK with a not flip should do it.

```
WHERE (NOT ((JOHN = 'OK') AND (JILL = 'OK') AND (GARY = 'OK') AND (JANE = 'OK') AND (JEFF= 'OK') AND (MICK = 'OK')))
```

Comment: I like this answer better just because it's going to be universally helpful. The answer I supplied was very specific to this case. I like it. Thanks, David.

Answer (score 2):

WHERE JOHN+JILL+GARY+JANE+JEFF+MICK <> 'okokokokokok'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a WHERE clause that looks like this:

```
WHERE JOHN = 'NOPE'
  OR JILL = 'NOPE'
  OR GARY = 'NOPE'
  OR JANE = 'NOPE'
  OR JEFF = 'NOPE'
  OR MICK = 'NOPE'
```

Comment: Thank you for trying. As far as I know, this might work if the query results were as simple as 'NOPE' or 'OK'. In reality, 'NOPE' can be 1 of dozens of things. And, those dozens of things will continually evolve and while technically possible, is not feasible to build the query this way.

Comment: @bteague if you have multiple things use WHERE ColumnName IN('value1', 'value2') or INNER JOIN it to a temp table of variables.